# referring to an object with a space in R

Tags: r, list, names

I have created a nested list:

```
my_list <- list(A = "first item", 
                B = "second item")
```

and given this list the name 'list 1':

```
vector_names <- c("list 1", "list 2")
assign(vector_names[[1]], my_list)
```

However, now I want to use the object `list 1` inside of a nested list, to obtain:

```
final_list <- list("1st_list" = list(A = "first item", 
                                     B = "second item"))
```

How can I refer to the list without copying it again? I tried:

```
final_list <- list("1st_list" = 'list 1')
```

but this doesn't return the Object `list 1`, it return a character vector 'list 1'.

Answer (score 3):

As there is space in object names, use backquote instead of single/double quote

```
list("1st_list" = `list 1`)
```

-output

```
$`1st_list`
$`1st_list`$A
[1] "first item"

$`1st_list`$B
[1] "second item"
```